# fields from useFieldArray is not in sync with updated state using react form hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, user-interface, react-hooks

Here is My component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { ActiveLearningPathDetails, MileStone, Todo } from "src/types";
import { useForm, useFieldArray, FieldArrayWithId, Controller, FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as R from "ramda";
import ADD_ICON from "src/assets/images/add-icon.svg";
import EDIT_ICON from "src/assets/images/edit-icon.svg";
import DUPLICATE_ICON from "src/assets/images/duplicate-icon.svg";
import DELETE_ICON from "src/assets/images/delete-icon.svg";
import { DateUtils } from "src/utils";
import "./MileStonesActionView.css";
import { MileStoneStatus } from "src/enums";
import { MileStonesActionTodoView } from "src/components";
import { UUIDUtils } from "src/utils/UUIDUtils";

export interface MileStonesActionViewProps {
    milestones: MileStone[];
    onSave: (milestones: MileStone[]) => void;
    activeLearningPath: ActiveLearningPathDetails;
}

export interface TodoFormData extends Todo {
    
}

export interface MileStoneFormData {
    milestone_id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    started_date: number;
    start_date: number;
    target_date: string;
    end_date: string;
    update_frequency_pattern: string;
    message_sequence_id: null | string;
    status: string;
    todos: TodoFormData[];
    
}

export interface MileStonesFormData {
    milestones: MileStoneFormData[]
}

export const MileStonesActionView = React.memo((props: MileStonesActionViewProps) => {

    const [rerender, setReRender] = React.useState(0);
    const [mileStonesInEditMode, setMileStonesInEditMode] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

    const methods = useForm<MileStonesFormData>({
        defaultValues: {
            milestones: props.milestones.map(item => {
                return {
                    ...R.clone(item),
                    
                    target_date: DateUtils.convertEpochToDateString(item.target_date),
                    end_date: DateUtils.convertEpochToDateString(item.end_date),
                    todos: item.todos.map(todoItem => {
                        return {
                            ...R.clone(todoItem),
                            
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    });
    const { control, handleSubmit, register, setValue, getValues, formState: { errors } } = methods;

    const { fields, append, remove, insert, update } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: 'milestones'
    });


    const onSubmit = (data: MileStonesFormData) => {
        console.log(data);
    };



    const createMileStoneCopy = (milestone: MileStoneFormData) => {
        return {
            ...R.clone(milestone),
            todos: milestone.todos.map(todoItem => {
                return {
                    ...R.clone(todoItem)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    const getEmptyMilestoneCopy = (isEditMode = false) => {
        return {
            milestone_id: UUIDUtils.getUUIDWithoutDashes(),
            name: '',
            description: '',
            started_date: Date.now() / 1000,
            start_date: Date.now() / 1000,
            target_date: DateUtils.convertEpochToDateString(Date.now() / 1000),
            end_date: DateUtils.convertEpochToDateString(Date.now() / 1000),
            update_frequency_pattern: '',
            message_sequence_id: null,
            status: MileStoneStatus.NOT_STARTED,
            todos: [],
            isEditMode: isEditMode
        } as MileStoneFormData
    }





    const getMileStoneEditView = (milestone: FieldArrayWithId<MileStonesFormData, "milestones", "id">, index: number) => {

        return (
            <div className="milestones-action-edit-view">
                <div className="milestone-input-section">
                    <label htmlFor={`milestones.${index}.name`} className="milestone-label">Milestone Title</label>
                    <input
                        className="milestone-title-input milestone-form-input"
                        placeholder="E.g. Understanding the Basics"
                        {...register(`milestones.${index}.name`)}

                    />
                </div>
                <div className="milestone-input-section">
                    <label htmlFor={`milestones.${index}.description`} className="milestone-label">Description</label>
                    <textarea
                        className="milestone-description-input milestone-form-input"
                        placeholder="Add description"
                        rows={5}
                        {...register(`milestones.${index}.description`)}
                    />
                </div>

                <MileStonesActionTodoView
                    activeLearningPath={props.activeLearningPath}
                    milestonesIndex={index}
                />

                <div className="milestone-input-section">
                    <label htmlFor={`milestones.${index}.target_date`} className="milestone-label">Target Date</label>
                    <input
                        className="milestone-target-date-input milestone-form-input"
                        type="date"

                        {...register(`milestones.${index}.target_date`)}
                    />
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }


    const getMileStoneNormalView = (milestone: FieldArrayWithId<MileStonesFormData, "milestones", "id">, index: number) => {

        return (
            <div className="milestones-action-normal-view-with-add d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div className="milestone-action-normal-view flex-row align-item-center milestone-info-wrapper">
                    <div className="d-flex flex-column  milestone-details">
                        <h6 className="milestone-title ">{milestone.name}</h6>
                        <p className="milestone-date">{DateUtils.formatDate(DateUtils.convertDateStringToEpoch(milestone.target_date), 'DD/MM/YYYY')}</p>
                        <p className="milestone-description ">{milestone.description}<b className="view-more-text cursor-pointer ">View More</b></p>

                    </div>
                    <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-between milestone-actions">
                        <img src={EDIT_ICON} className="curs-ptr" alt="edit" onClick={() => {
                           
                            setMileStonesInEditMode(prev => ([...prev, milestone.milestone_id]));

                        }} />
                        <img src={DUPLICATE_ICON} className="curs-ptr" alt="duplicate" onClick={() => {

                            insert(index, createMileStoneCopy(milestone));

                        }} />
                        <img src={DELETE_ICON} className="curs-ptr" alt="delete" onClick={() => {
                            remove(index);
                            setMileStonesInEditMode(prev => prev.filter(item => item != milestone.id));
                        }} />
                    </div>


                </div>
                <img src={ADD_ICON} className="curs-ptr" alt="add" onClick={() => {
                    insert(index, getEmptyMilestoneCopy(true));
                    setMileStonesInEditMode(prev => ([...prev, milestone.milestone_id]));
                }} />

            </div>

        );
    }

    console.log("Milestones", getValues())
    return (
        <div className="milestones-edit-view-wrapper">
            <FormProvider
            {...methods}
            >
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} >
                    {
                        fields.map((milestone, index) => {
                            console.log("fields of milestnes rerendering", fields)
                            return (
                                <div key={milestone.milestone_id}>
                                    {mileStonesInEditMode.includes(milestone.milestone_id) ? getMileStoneEditView(milestone, index) : getMileStoneNormalView(milestone, index)}
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </form>
            </FormProvider>
            <div className="save-btn">
                Save
            </div>
        </div>
    );

});
```

Here is my child component:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./MileStonesActionTodoView.css";
import { Control, UseFormRegister, UseFormSetValue, useFieldArray, useFormContext, useWatch } from 'react-hook-form';
import { MileStonesFormData, TodoFormData } from '../MileStonesActionView';
import ADD_ICON from "src/assets/images/add-icon.svg";
import DELETE_ICON from "src/assets/images/delete-icon.svg";
import DONE_ICON from "src/assets/images/done-icon.svg";
import { ActiveLearningPathDetails } from 'src/types';
import * as R from "ramda";
import { UUIDUtils } from 'src/utils/UUIDUtils';



export interface MileStonesActionTodoViewProps {
    milestonesIndex: number;
    activeLearningPath: ActiveLearningPathDetails;
}

export const MileStonesActionTodoView: React.FC<MileStonesActionTodoViewProps> = React.memo(({ milestonesIndex,  activeLearningPath}) => {
    
    const {control, register, setValue} = useFormContext<MileStonesFormData>();

    const { fields, remove, insert, update } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: `milestones.${milestonesIndex}.todos`
    });

    

    const [editModeIds, setEditModeIds] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

    const addTodoItem = (milestoneIndex: number, todoIndex: number) => {
        const todoId = UUIDUtils.getUUIDWithoutDashes();
        insert(todoIndex, {
            assignee: activeLearningPath.mentee_id,
            description: '',
            is_completed: false,
            todo_id: todoId,
            
        });
        
        return todoId;
       
    }

    const removeTodoItem = (milestoneIndex: number, todoIndex: number) => {
       remove(todoIndex);
    }


    const getTodoNormalView = (todo: TodoFormData, milestoneIndex: number, index: number) => {

        return (
            <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between milestone-todo-action-item">
                <span className="milestone-todo-action-desc">{todo.description}</span>
                <div className="milestone-todo-actions">
                    <img src={DELETE_ICON} className="curs-ptr" alt="" onClick={() => {
                        removeTodoItem(milestoneIndex, index);
                        setEditModeIds(prev => {
                            const result =  prev.filter(item=> item != todo.todo_id);
                            
                            return result;
                        });
                    }} />
                    <img src={ADD_ICON} className="curs-ptr" alt="" onClick={() => {
                        const todoId = addTodoItem(milestoneIndex, index);
                        setEditModeIds(prev => {
                            const result = [...prev, todoId];
                            
                            return result;
                        });
                        
                    }} />

                </div>
            </div>
        )

    }

    const getTodoEditView = (todo: TodoFormData, milestoneIndex: number, index: number) => {
        return <div className="milestone-input-section milestone-todo-edit-view">
            {/* <label htmlFor={`milestones.${milestoneIndex}.todos.${index}.description`} className="milestone-label">Milestone Title</label> */}
            <textarea
                className=" milestone-form-input milestone-todo-desc-input"
                placeholder="Achievement Description"
                rows={5}
                {...register(`milestones.${milestoneIndex}.todos.${index}.description`, {
                    required:'Achievement description is required'
                })}
            >
            </textarea>
            <img src={DONE_ICON} className='milestone-todo-desc-save-icon curs-ptr' alt="" onClick={() => {
                    
                    setEditModeIds(prev => {
                        const result =  prev.filter(item=> item != todo.todo_id);
                        
                        return result;
                    });
                }} />
        </div>
    }

    
    return (
        <div className="milestone-expected-achievements">
            <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <span className="milestone-expected-achievements-title">Expected Achievements</span>
                <img src={ADD_ICON} className="curs-ptr" alt="" onClick={() => {
                    const todoId = addTodoItem(milestonesIndex, 0);
                   
                    setEditModeIds(prev => {
                        const result = [...prev, todoId];
                    
                        return result;
                    });
                }} />
            </div>
            {
                fields.map((item, todoIndex) => {
                    
                    return <div key={item.todo_id}>
                        {editModeIds.includes(item.todo_id) ? getTodoEditView(item, milestonesIndex, todoIndex) : getTodoNormalView(item, milestonesIndex, todoIndex)}
                    </div>
                })
            }


        </div>
    )
});
```

I am trying to add a todo, when i type and click done. The state of todo description from fields array in MileStonesActionTodoView is not in sync with the updated value from useForm. I tried using useWatch it works but it kills the optimisation done by react hook forms. Please help me out in fixing the issue.